# How to modify the display of custom fields of user's profile

Tags: user, template-override, joomla-3.7

I've added some custom fields to Users. There's a menu entry for User Profile in the Front End. I'd like to change its display i.e. see the custom fields **before** the Basic Settings.
I didn't find a way to do that within Joomla.
Will I have to duplicate the template and create/modify an override ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be able to reorder the elements using CSS or JavaScript without having to update the HTML code e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/220273/1983389

Comment: Plenty of solutions ! Thanks a lot ! I'll try that in Sept and let people know.